# Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to make a POST request in Angular 5 that accepts `text/plain` as response. Angular is calling a method which expects `JSON` as response and hence throws an error when response comes while trying to parse the response.

I tried calling method with parameter `{responseType: 'text'}` but VS code is showing it as an error and I am also getting an error in the console when the application is compiled.

Below is the Angular 5 code for a POST request that expects a response as `text/plain`.

```
this.http
.post<string>(this.loginUrl, this.user, {responseType: 'text'}) // error in this line
.subscribe(
    (data) => this.success(data),
    (error) => this.failure(error)
);
```

While compilation the following error show in the console:

```
ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts(47,47): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The version of `post` accepting `responseType:'text'` is not generic, since the result type is already clear (ie `string`)

```
this.http
.post(this.loginUrl, this.user, {responseType: 'text'}) // no generic parameter
.subscribe(
    (data) => this.success(data), // data is string
    (error) => this.failure(error)
);
```

Comment: I still do not understand what was causing this issue? Why by adding .post<string> could resolve to a conflict with reponseType: 'text' ?

Comment: @LoganWlv because there are multiple overloads, and the overload with `responseType: 'text'` is not generic, and the overload that is generic that is generic only allows `'json'` for `responseType`

Comment: It's not working for me in Angular 9, here is what I had to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60693216/6410464

Answer (score 19):

Here is an approach if you don't want to remove `<string>` to keep your response strongly typed:

```
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' // We send JSON
      }),
      responseType: 'text' as 'json'  // We accept plain text as response.
    };
    return this.http.post<string>(this.setBaseUrl, body, httpOptions);
```

Replace `text` with [valid responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) according the data that you want to receive.

Comment: I don't see how removing `<string>` is any more of a hack than setting the responseType to `'text' as 'json'`. Is there any functional difference between the two?

Comment: I don't think there should be a functional difference.
The only reason I would call it a better approach is in typescript, explicit mention of datatype is preferred; which is not violated here.

Comment: Actually removing <string> is not a hack and doesn't go against the typescript approach. In fact, it is Angular's httpClient's implementation that decides that if you use the resposneType: 'text, it is unneccesary to provide a generic and hence this overloaded method doesn't even accept a generic type.  If anything, telling typescript to treat 'text' as 'json' is definitely a hack.

Comment: `'text' as 'json'` is type assertion. Since I am expecting to receive a `json`, I am just telling typescript to behave as if the result would be JSON, please google the keyword `as`. It's always preferred to keep things strongly typed where possible (please google the reasons for it).
If you don't care about type, please use `any` (`any` is default; it's too permissive, allows anything to be done to the variable; not recommended when it's possible to avoid -- omitting type makes it `any`).
I've removed the word `hack` as I don't have time to reply to more comments on it. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

Just remove "**string**" from your request. Try this:

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl, this.user, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
    (data) => this.success(data),
    (error) => this.failure(error)
);
```

Comment: This is only a hack. I don't know if at the time of asking the question a better solution was possible or not, but today certainly you can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/60693216/6410464

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this particular issue today myself. After searching for a little and figuring that the responseType option *should* exist, I managed to get it work as below:

```
let requestOptions: Object = { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials),
    responseType: 'text'
}    

return this.httpClient.get<any>(
                this.environment.tokenHost + this.environment.authenticationURL,
                requestOptions
            )
            .subscribe(result => {
                // do stuff
            });
```

Setting the `responseType` like that makes it work, compared to configuring it in the 'request' itself.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl,this.user,{headers:
new HttpHeaders({'content-type':'application/json'}), responseType:'text'})
.subscribe((r)=>{console.log(r)})
```

Edit

It is wierd but creating header object separately like below snippet

```
let headerOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders(
     {'content-type':'application/json'}),
       responseType:'text'
 }
this.http.post(this.loginUrl,this.user, headerOptions)
 .subscribe((r)=>{console.log(r)})
```

would throw error in VS code, so the idea is to pass the entire object in inline post request like above would solve the compilation error.

Comment: Can you add description?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, no idea why we can't create the header options separately for reusability etc. Inline only if you want to customize responseType

Comment: responseType: 'text' as 'text' works when you have a separate object. Give it a try.