# Angular Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse when expecting a string

Tags: json, angular

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to use the checkout facility for stripe using this documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment

I have configured my API to just return the checkoutid as a string.
The Angular service just calls the controller. When I run my code I actually get a nice 200 response and I can see the checkout id in the response body, but Angular throws an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (https://127.0.0.1:4200/vendor.js:18780:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask

The service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StripeService {
  private endpoint: string = 'stripe';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  checkout(priceId: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<string>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${priceId}`)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

and I am invoking it like this:

```
this.stripeService
  .checkout(this.button.priceId)
  .subscribe((checkoutId: string) => {
    console.log(checkoutId);
    // this.stripe
    //   .redirectToCheckout({
    //     sessionId: checkoutId,
    //   })
    //   .then(function (result) {
    //     // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    //     // error, display the localized error message to your customer
    //     // using `result.error.message`.
    //   });
  });
```

If I look in the network tab I can see this:

[image]

But the console actually shows this:

[image]

Does anyone have a scooby why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably the response is a string and you haven't specified the response type. Try the following

```js
this.http.get(
  `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${priceId}`, 
  { responseType: 'text' }
)
```

Default response type is [`json`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L130).

Comment: I'm new to angular I did this and it said: `: error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.`

Comment: script is: `this.http.get<string>(`${url}`, {responseType: 'text'});`

Comment: @PauAI: You need to remove the generic type casting `<string>`. It must be `this.http.get(\`${url}\`, {responseType: 'text'});`. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49771603/6513921

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when my API return doesent match with my deserializable object on Angular. At first, try to check your returns entities