# Angular HTTP client accepts responseType: 'json' but not responseType: 'text'?

Tags: angular

Can someone tell me why `'text'` here in invalid but `'json'` is valid? Makes no sense how one string is accepted but the other isn't.

This is valid

```
return this._http.get<string>(url, { responseType: 'json'}).pipe(map(response => body));
```

This isn't

```
return this._http.get<string>(url, { responseType: 'text'}).pipe(map(response => body));
```

Even [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) say 'text' is an accepted argument:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'
```

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
   Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
     Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
   Overload 2 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
     Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
   Overload 3 of 15, '(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
     Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

Comment: There isn't a definition for `responseType: 'text'` (or any `responseType` other than `'json'`, IIRC) with a generic response type, because the response type is always `string`. Just do `return this._http.get(...)...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771603/types-of-property-responsetype-are-incompatible)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.

```
    return this._http
        .get<string>(url, { responseType: 'text' } as Record<string, unknown>)
        .pipe(map((response) => body));
```